# how to pronounce "Daniel Dunglas Home" correctly in american english?

Tags: pronunciation

> how to pronounce "Daniel Dunglas Home" correctly in american english?

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Dunglas_Home

Comment: You should pronounce it the way Mr Home would have pronounced it (as given in the link).

Comment: @ Weather Vane like: /daniel daanglaas hum/?

Comment: The link says "Hume". There was a politician in my living memory with a similarly pronounced surname: Sir Alec Douglas-Home. After all, that was his name, and it is respectful to call someone in their preferred way.

Comment: @i found it. i think you are right Alec Douglas-Home pronounced /ˌælɪk ˌdʌɡləs ˈhjuːm/, so "Daniel" pronounced /ˈdænjəl/ and "home" pronounced /ˈhjuːm/. but i am not sure about dunglas, does it pronounce like Douglas?

Comment: It's spelt "Dunglas Home" but its pronounced "Throat wobbler mangrove"  (joke, monty python)

Answer (score 3):

It is important to remember that this is a *Scottish* name and as such has a different pronunciation to English as spoken in England.

- "Daniel" would be pronounced as you would expect.
- "Dunglas" would be said as "dung-glass" with full emphasis on the double-s as you would pronounce the word "glass" - not the short, clipped "lus" as some English names/words might be said.
- "Home" is pronounced as "hume" (also the same as the place name / surname "Hulme"), as the Wikipedia entry you quoted from suggests.

Whenever faced with pronouncing any non-English name, it is a choice to attempt an accurate pronunciation in the original language or accent, to Anglicise it, or to make a compromise between the two. If you follow my guide above, I believe that should be a satisfactory English pronunciation of the Scottish name.

[This documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1jAAm-nmoU) about the man is a good source to hear his name pronounced.

Comment: "dung-lass" or "dung-glass"? Having never heard the name, I'd (perhaps incorrectly) assume the latter. Where are you getting this information from? Can you add your sources please?

Comment: @CJDennis I've added a link where you can hear his name pronounced.

Comment: Thanks! So my assumption was correct. You should update your answer to include a hard "g".

Comment: @CJDennis I heard it slightly differently but on listening a few times I agree with you, updated.